# Hashmap with Arraylist as values Android

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I am developing an android application and I am using a Hashmap to store some data the app works fine when I define the Arraylist this way

```
ArrayList<String> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
```

but the app crashes when I change it to:

```
ArrayList<String> eventList = hmap.get(date);
```

I need to know the reason why?.
And here is the whole function in case you need to have a look

```
HashMap<Date, ArrayList<String>> hmap = new HashMap<>();
void eventMaker(String d, String ev)  {
     Date date = null;
     try {
            date = df.parse(d);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
     long epoch = date.getTime();
     Event event = new Event(Color.RED,epoch,ev);
     compactCalendar.addEvent(event);
     ArrayList<String> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
     eventList.add(ev);
     hmap.put(date,eventList);
 }
```

Comment: What does your `LogCat` Message show

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.awarrior.calendar/com.example.awarrior.calendar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: I tried to solve it this way

     if(hmap.get(date).isEmpty()){
            ArrayList<String> eventList =new ArrayList<>();
            eventList.add(ev);
            hmap.put(date,eventList);
        }
        else{
            ArrayList<String> eventList = (ArrayList<String>)hmap.get(date);
            eventList.add(ev);
            hmap.put(date,eventList);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the value of Hashmap to required type .

```
  ArrayList<String> eventList =(ArrayList<String>) hmap.get(date);
```

Comment: If there is just one string ev , then why are you using ArrayList ?

Comment: No the function may be called many times but I want to store the previous events

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to get a value of a key that does not exist, I solved it like this:

```
if(!hmap.containsKey(date)){
            ArrayList<String> eventList =new ArrayList<>();
            eventList.add(ev);
            hmap.put(date,eventList);
        }
        else{
            ArrayList<String> eventList = hmap.get(date);
            eventList.add(ev);
            hmap.put(date,eventList);
        }
```